# How to design sequential IO-bound and CPU-bound computing inside iterations

Tags: python, multithreading, sqlalchemy, python-asyncio, concurrent.futures

I share a snippet of code where I want to show my use-case, a loop where I iterate over groups of tasks

```
   for idx, task in enumerate(tasks):
       try:
          manager.open_connection(idx)
          for jdx, subtask in enumerate(task):
             subtask.io_bound_read_from_sql()
             subtask.io_bound_read_from_fs()
             subtask.cpu_bound_compute()
             subtask.io_bound_write_to_sql()
       finally:
          manager.close_connection(idx)
```

To date, the instance "manager" wraps SQLAlchemy engine objects in order to manage SQL connections by [pools of connections](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/pooling.html#module-sqlalchemy.pool). Both the engine and pool objects are said to be "lazy" as the actual connection is establish when doing the transactions as far as I understood.

Both methods `io_bound_read_from_sql()` and `io_bound_write_to_sql()` actually run SQL transactions by the "engines" of SQL Alchemy on a dedicated database identified by `idx`
The idea is to group related tasks referring to the same database, labeled as "subtasks" so that the outer loop iterates over these groups using the same database and the subtasks perform transaction on the same database (i.e. without switching to another database). The idea was to micro-manage these groups so that not to open all the connections/pools of connections together and then keep them alive even if not used and to avoid timeouts/reconnections.

The `open_connection(idx)` and `close_connection(idx)` methods actually wrap, among other things, the call to "create_engine" and "engine.dispose" of SQL Alchemy.
Also, `io_bound_read_from_fs()` wraps, among other things, asyncio-based concurrent IO functions.

The sequence of functions called on the `subtask` inside the inner loop are sequential, but indipendent. For instance, if `subtask` with `jdx` counter equal to `1` is doing `io_bound_write_to_sql()`, I would like `subtask` with `jdx` 2 to start concurrently `io_bound_read_from_sql()`.

My question is how to design this proof of concepts. I wish not to use `multiprocessing` because it is too complicated to me, and I wish to leave multiprocessing for horizontal scaling in the futures. I wish to use only 1 process, and use `multithreading` or asyncio to concurrently manage the works of the tasks. I'm entusiastic about `asyncio`, and I saw SQL Alchemy also has asyncio-based adapters to work with `asyncio` instead of `multithreading` \ `concurrent.futures` (?).
Do you have any suggestions or experience/insights to share?

Comment: I feel like you are overcomplicating things. What stops you from simply from launching one `asyncio.Task` for each of your tasks and letting them run concurrently, `awaiting` their respective subtasks internally? Or maybe rate-limit the number of concurrent tasks with a queue to a reasonable number of inflight tasks. Otherwise it sounds like you want one task per sub-task category, handling all tasks for this category; maybe connected via a queue from sub-task to sub-task. Is that what you want?

Comment: I assume that *manager* is available globally and that the various *subtask* methods are utilising *manager* with respect to the database connection. If that's the case **and** if the connection is thread safe, then multithreading would be a good option